# Unexpected gradient behavior with the Particle Info Node (index and age) and fluid/liquid simulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, shaders, fluid-simulation

My goal is to get a gradient from a baked fluid/liquid simulation, ideally with a baked mesh. Below is a rough example of that idea.
[image: text]

But when I use a *Particle Info* node *Index*, the gradient has this odd square pattern instead.

(I am rendering icosphere objects as particles with this shader.)
[image: text]

Additionally, when trying to use the *Age* property instead, all the particles seemingly have the same age and appear as the same color.
[image: text]

I have also not yet figured out how to get the colors from the particle objects to change the colors on a baked mesh, though.

[Here is a Discord download link to the .blend file and its cache, zipped as a .7z.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/689102333103439964/982568542144720956/STACKEXCHANGE_june_4.7z)
[Here is a Google Drive link to the .blend file and its cache, inside of a folder.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/184gbcO_UY11LXM_gaF05yMlWmWjmbeII?usp=sharing)